# From Terminal, how would I copy a text file from the desktop into a USB?

Tags: command

I'm just trying to repeat command line basics.

Comment: Assuming you are currently in desktop (check using `pwd` command), use the command as `cp filename /media/usb-dev-path`

Comment: First,  run `mount` to find out where your USB is actually mounted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to locate your USB in `/media` or inside `/media/youUsername/`

Your Desktop is located in

```
/home/Desktop
```

so copy a file with

```
cp /home/Desktop/filename.txt /media/USBDRIVENAME/
```